# Two dimensional array from standard input without knowing columns size

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How do I print a two dimensional array from a standard input where I know the row size, but not column size?

First line of standard input will be row size and next few lines will be number of rows with inputs for each element of column separated by space. 
e.g.

```
3
1 2 3
3 4 5
6 9 3
```

This is what I am trying with my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = sc.nextInt(); // Number of rows
        int[][] arr = new int[rows][];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the column values,
then you'll need to split each line.
When you split the lines, you will know the number of columns.
For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "3\n" +
            "1 2 3\n" +
            "3 4 5\n" +
            "6 9 3\n";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

    int rows = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    int[][] arr = new int[rows][];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        arr[i] = lineToIntArray(line);
    }
}

private int[] lineToIntArray(String line) {
    String[] cols = line.split(" ");
    int[] ints = new int[cols.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; ++i) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(cols[i]);
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Or `lineToIntArray` using Java 8:

```
private int[] lineToIntArray(String line) {
    return Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

Comment: But you can't enter more rows than allowed, this makes it keep entering infinite rows. Also the example I gave is a sample input with row size 3. Also I should be able to finish input my array before I can print it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
String values[] = line.split(" ");
// Now each item of values contains an item of the line, convert it to the type you want and store in your two dimensional array, line by line
// the row count will be values.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the first line.

```
List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
sc.nextLine(); //skip line 1
while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
    lines.add(sc.nextLine().split(" "));
```

To print:

```
lines.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all lines are read into `input` as 1 `String`, this should work..

```
Stream.of(input.split("\n")).map(line -> line.split(" ")).toArray(String[][]::new)
```